# Kubernetes delete deployment after script execution

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, locust

I'm working on creating a distributed locust service for benchmarking and REST API testing in the platform. Architecture is as follows:

1. First pod running a docker image with master flag for controlling the whole process
2. A collection of pods running a docker image with worker flag which will make the work (which can vary depending on the requeriments)

Deployment and Service files are:

**01-locust-master.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: locust-master
  labels:
    name: locust
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    name: locust
    role: master
  ports:
    - port: 8089
      protocol: TCP
      name: master-web
    - port: 5557
      protocol: TCP
      name: master-port1
    - port: 5558
      protocol: TCP
      name: master-port2
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: locust-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: locust
      role: master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: locust
        role: master
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: locust
          image: locust-image:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: LOCUST_MODE
              value: master
            - name: LOCUST_LOCUSTFILE_PATH
              value: "/locust-tasks/locustfiles/the_file.py"
            - name: LOCUST_TARGET_HOST
              value: "the_endpoint"
            - name: LOCUST_USERS
              value: !!integerEnv 300
            - name: LOCUST_SPAWN_RATE
              value: !!integerEnv 100
            - name: LOCUST_TEST_TIME
              value: "5m"
            - name: LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR
              value: "/locust-tasks/locust-output"
            - name: LOCUST_TEST_API_TOKEN
              value: "some_api_topken"
            - name: LOCUST_S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET
              value: "s3-bucket"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8089
            - containerPort: 5557
            - containerPort: 5558
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 2000m
              memory: 2048Mi
```

**02-locust-worker.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: locust-worker
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: locust
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: locust
        role: worker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: locust
          image: locust:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: LOCUST_MODE
              value: worker
            - name: LOCUST_MASTER_NODE_HOST
              value: locust-master
            - name: LOCUST_LOCUSTFILE_PATH
              value: "/locust-tasks/locustfiles/the_file.py"
            - name: LOCUST_TARGET_HOST
              value: "the_endpoint"
            - name: LOCUST_TEST_API_TOKEN
              value: "the_api_token"
            - name: LOCUST_S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET
              value: "s3_bucket"
          resources: 
            limits:
              cpu: 1500m
              memory: 850Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 1200m
              memory: 768Mi
```

***DockerFile***

```
FROM python:3.7.3

# Install packages
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install awscli

# Add locustfiles
COPY common/ /locust-tasks/common/
COPY templates/ /locust-tasks/templates/
COPY locustfiles/ /locust-tasks/locustfiles/

# Set the entrypoint
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 5557 5558 8089
```

***docker-entrypoint.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash -x

LOCUST_MODE=${LOCUST_MODE:="standalone"}
LOCUST_MASTER=${LOCUST_MASTER:=""}
LOCUST_LOCUSTFILE_PATH=${LOCUST_LOCUSTFILE_PATH:="/locust-tasks/locustfiles/the_file.py"}
LOCUST_TARGET_HOST=${LOCUST_TARGET_HOST:="the_endpoint"}
LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR=${LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR:="/locust-tasks/locust-output"}
LOCUST_TEST_API_TOKEN=${LOCUST_TEST_API_TOKEN:="the_token"}
LOCUST_S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET=${LOCUST_S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET:="s3_bucket"}

cd /locust-tasks

if [[ ! -e $LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR ]]; then
    mkdir $LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR
elif [[ ! -d $LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR ]]; then
    echo "$LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR already exists but is not a directory" 1>&2
fi

LOCUST_PATH="/usr/local/bin/locust"
LOCUST_FLAGS="-f $LOCUST_LOCUSTFILE_PATH --host=$LOCUST_TARGET_HOST --csv=$LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR/locust-${LOCUST_MODE}"

if [[ "$LOCUST_MODE" = "master" ]]; then
   LOCUST_FLAGS="$LOCUST_FLAGS --master --headless -u $LOCUST_USERS -r $LOCUST_SPAWN_RATE -t $LOCUST_TEST_TIME"
elif [[ "$LOCUST_MODE" = "worker" ]]; then
    LOCUST_FLAGS="$LOCUST_FLAGS --worker --master-host=$LOCUST_MASTER_NODE_HOST"
fi

auth_token=$LOCUST_TEST_API_TOKEN $LOCUST_PATH $LOCUST_FLAGS

# Copy test output files to S3
today=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")
S3_OUTPUT_DIR="s3://${LOCUST_S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET}/${today}/${HOSTNAME}"

echo "Copying locust output files from [$LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR] to S3 [$S3_OUTPUT_DIR]"

aws s3 cp --recursive $LOCUST_OUTPUT_DIR $S3_OUTPUT_DIR

retVal=$?
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Something went wrong, exit code is ${retVal}"
fi

exit $retVal
```

So my requeriment / idea is to run the script above and after that delete the whole thing. But instead of that, I'm getting and endless pods restarting:

```
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
locust-master-69b4547ddf-7fl4d   1/1     Running   4          23m
locust-worker-59b9689857-l5jhw   1/1     Running   4          23m
locust-worker-59b9689857-l5nd2   1/1     Running   4          23m
locust-worker-59b9689857-lwqbb   1/1     Running   4          23m
```

How can I delete both deployments after the shellscript ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/).

> As pods successfully complete, the Job tracks the successful
> completions. When a specified number of successful completions is
> reached, the task (ie, Job) is complete. Deleting a Job will clean up
> the Pods it created.

You can use ttl mechanism for cleaning up the finished job by specifying the `.spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished` field of the Job

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs

Comment: Thanks Sam, will look into that right now and will post here the result!

Comment: @GeorgeFandango cool

Comment: Hi @Sam, after some tests, you're right: I need jobs to perform this task. I've modified the yaml files changing the deployment definition to a job and it works, but not as I spected. The pods still remain in a "completed" status but they're not deleted automatically. I've been reading the docs and as stated at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-termination-and-cleanup a manually cleanup is needed, which is useless

Comment: @GeorgeFandango you may try ttlSecondsAfterFinished,  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs

Comment: Hello @Sam, thank you so much for your recommendations. As far as I know, this ttlSecondsAfterFinished is a beta feature which I think it works for server versions > 1.21. Our server version is 1.18+ so I think it won't do until we update the server version.